# Equivalent Sql group by to Linq to get value and text properties

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been spending quite a long time trying to make a Linq query with a group by in it, just to return a List for a SelectList with the common **Text** an **Value** properties.

I think and still have hope that it does not have to be as difficult as it looks, and i prefer to think that is me and my tired brain sometimes, but honestly i gave up.

I've been able to achieve what i wanted with raw sql but, it's just simple curiosity because I deny to think Linq is that much of a time waster...

So please if someone out there, who knows how to do this in a Linq lambda query, please illuminate my tired brain...

> > What i got with raw sql and want with linq lambda (it works perfectly, took me 2 minutes and I can populate my MultiSelectFor nicely):

```
 string sql = " select [AlphabeticCode] as 'Value', concat([AlphabeticCode], ' - ', Currency) as Text from [table] " +
                         " group by AlphabeticCode, Currency; ";

            var currency = db.Database
                             .SqlQuery<Models.myViewModels.LinqToSql.SelectListViewModel>(sql)
                             .ToList();

            model.currency = new SelectList(currency, "Value", "Text");
```

> > What i thought i was doing right, made me spend a lonnnng time and ended up giving me a collection inside my text property... not what i wanted at all... (I know is not correct, i tried quite a few more options), but this one kinda made sense to me, please, give a reason to keep working with this weird Linq thing...

```
 var cc = db.table.GroupBy(item => item.Currency)
                 .Select(group =>
                     new
                     {
                         Value = group.Key,
                         Text = group.Select(m => m.Currency).Take(1), // here is where i want just ONE string that is the currency name
                     }
                 )
                 .ToList();
```

Thank you so much to whoever takes some time to read my frustrations...

Comment: do you really want to group by or just get the unique AlphabeticalCode + Currancy pairs formatted as strings?

Comment: AlphabeticalCode + Currancy pairs formatted as strings so i can do later 
model.currency = new SelectList(currency, "Value", "Text"); but of course grouped by or distinctly by AlphabeticCode

Comment: Sorry are you just having troubles grouping by two columns, look likes a pretty trivial query so I am probably missing something?

Comment: Thats why i'm frustrated, i'm not an expert with LInq, so i need some advices, I just want a var currency = { value : xx , Text: xx} coming from a lambda linq query but i need to group or dictinct by a field. so no matter if i have 20 records with EUR value, i only get it once from the query.... all the examples help i've seen or tried give me a collection when i group by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you need but I think this will make the same query as your SQL

```
    var items = from item in table
                group item by new { item.AlphabeticCode, item.Currency } into g
                select new { Value = g.Key.AlphabeticCode, Text = g.Key.AlphabeticCode + " - " + g.Key.Currency }; 
     //Fluent or inline 
     table.
           GroupBy(i => new { i.AlphabeticCode, i.Currency }).
           Select(g => new { Value = g.Key.AlphabeticCode, Text = g.Key.AlphabeticCode + " - " + g.Key.Currency });
```

Comment: Yeah that would do it, thanks. Would you tell me how to do it with lambda syntax?